# How to custom design android Edit text

Tags: android, xml

Hello guys I have in mind a particular design that I want to implement in my android app but it has been very difficult for me to come up with a way to do it here's what i'm looking for.

what i'm looking for:
[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#C5CAE9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/form_username"/>
```

`

Comment: Which part is difficult?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nine-patch to do this.  NinePatch images are PNG images on which you can specify zones to be allowed/denied to hold text. So you can design your wanted image (with your icons) and deny writing text upon the icons parts and when you are done you set the image as background. In Android Studio, there is a useful WYSIWIG  tool for that.  For more details, please have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/your_background_with_orange_stroke">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/your_left_one_drawable"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/form_username"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/your_right_pen_drawable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and let see if this is what you want.

create drawable shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />  <-- change it to your need radius
    <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="@color/chocolate" />
    <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
</shape>
```

create layout

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

     <EditText
           android:id="@+id/keyword"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:hint="Type keyword..."
           android:padding="15dp"
           android:textSize="16sp"
           android:inputType="textPersonName"
           android:background="@drawable/shape"/>

     <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/icon"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:tint="@color/chocolate"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:src="@drawable/icon_calendar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```